# Fixing Outlook Web App on Chrome for Mac

Tags: mac, google-chrome, microsoft-outlook

Chrome 37 disables showModalDialog. This [causes lots of pain](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=408286) for those of us stuck using Outlook Web App to access our work email. In particular it breaks attachments, access to the address book inside email composition, and a number of other things.

Chrome policies [provides a way to re-enable showModalDialog](http://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#EnableDeprecatedWebPlatformFeatures) until May 2015, but [the only instructions I can find](http://codecorner.galanter.net/2014/09/02/reenable-showmodaldialog-in-chrome/) are Windows-specific--they require a registry edit.

How can I edit the Chrome policies on my mac to enable showModalDialog?

Comment: I had no problem finding out how to modify them.  You need [Workgroup Manager](http://www.chromium.org/administrators/mac-quick-start) with more information located [here](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-discuss/UyWZl9UAv4w) read all the replies because despite what your initial thoughts might be this is the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a file here:

```
/Library/Preferences/com.google.Chrome.plist
```

With the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>  
    <key>EnableDeprecatedWebPlatformFeatures</key>
    <array>
        <string>ShowModalDialog_EffectiveUntil20150430</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

From the terminal app, I used the command "sudo nano /Library/Preferences/com.google.Chrome.plist", then pasted the contents and hit ctrl+x to save. There are lots of other ways to do it though.

Here's the site that helped me figure this out: [How to Re-enable showModalDialog using Chrome on a Mac](http://blog.interdynartis.com/how-to-re-enable-showmodaldialog-using-chrome-on-a-mac)

NOTE: This is only a temporary solution! Google will officially disable the showModalDialog function in May of 2015, and [Mozilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=981796) and [Opera](https://dev.opera.com/blog/showmodaldialog/) have plans to follow suit.